# Qt5 QXmlStreamReader don't load any data

Tags: xml, qt5, atom-feed

I am trying to parse some xml file ( rss/atom data ) in Qt5, I am getting file from server trough QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply, then tried to put it into QXmlStreamReader but it does'nt take any data from reply.readAll(), I write it all to a file ( and it's okay, 15kb of txt ) and set device for streamreader on this file, but it too does not respond, when i try to move in this reader it's always behave like there is nothing there, some ideas what's happening?

```
QString xmlFileText = rep->readAll();
QXmlStreamReader xml(xmlFileText);
```

not working

```
QXmlStreamReader xml(&file);
```

not working

```
QXmlStreamReader xml();
xml.setDevice(&file)
```

not working

Is there any better option to parse xml file? It's normal atom channel, don't know whats happening.

Comment: Can you describe better what you mean by "not working"? How are you using the stream reader? What's "file" in the context above? Is it open?

Comment: @peppe file = downloaded from http xml file with atom data, yes it was open, reader was behaving like empty reader, i couldn't get any data from it, actually i copy some solution and it works, i pass QNetworkReply data to file, and then link it to reader, tried it before but now its working.